# Turning Div Id into input element without killing Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I've made a small on screen phone using HTML, CSS, JQuery and Javascript. I used a template Javascript file and chopped and changed to suit my needs but needed to adapt my HTML file slightly to do so, thus changing what was a form input field do just a DIV ID. The Javascript make the buttons pressed display on the 'screen', but I can no longer type into the screen as well, how can I add this functionality once more without killing the Javascript?

Here's the [`JS Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/3fjumo0n/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With HTML5, every element can be [editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable). Just change

```
<div id="Number"></div>
```

to

```
<div id="Number" contentEditable="true"></div>
```

and your screen will accept user input.

Comment: Fantastic! thank you. I hoped it would be a simple tag change :)

Comment: Thanks! contentEditable will come in handy!